# Control size of points in figure produced by knitr

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, sweave

I've used `knitr` to produce a PDF. This is a screenshot from 1 page of the PDF:

After a couple of hours of fiddling various `knitr` options (`fig.width`, `fig.height`, `out.height`, `out.width`), the page of the PDF looks half decent. But...the axis text, the annotations and the points in the plot are still too small relative to the text in the PDF.

Is there is a way to have `knitr` automatically size the text/points in the plot so fit well inside the PDF?

[image]

**EDIT: with the suggested fig.width="3.7" and out.width = "\\columnwidth"**

[image]

Comment: I usually try to make the figure about 3.5–4 inches wide for a two-column a4 paper layout, which needs almost no resizing. This way the font size, point, linewidth etc needs no further intervention.

Comment: I've changed `out.width="3.7in"` for 1 column and `out.width="7.5in"` for 2 columns . Is this what you meant? This has actually made the plots worse

Comment: it would be `fig.width = 3.7`, and leave out.width to default or perhaps `out.width = "\\columnwidth"`

Comment: I've tried `fig.width = 3.7` and `out.width = "\\columnwidth"`. This takes me even further from the desired plot. See attached.

Comment: looks fine to me, as far as point size and text size is concerned (wasn't this the question?). But you really should consider a fully reproducible minimal example if you want more specific advice. From what I see, you have a problem with x axis labels (too many breaks for the available space), and of course you should set fig.height to a smaller value, probably around 3 inches too. You could perhaps move the legend inside the plot panel, or above the plot, to better use the full column width.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `cex` and its friends like `cex.lab` and `cex.axis` (see `?par`).?